# salvar os cookies no array e depois imprimir

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte:
Toda vez que ele `click` no botão, o contador conte **+ 1**, e essa quantidade vai ser usada no `foreach` pra ele salvar no `cookies`.
veja o meu codigo:

```html
$contar = 0;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $contar = $contar + 1;
}

if (isset($_POST['ideia'])) {
  


$cookie_value= $_POST['ideia'];
foreach ($contar as $id) {

 setcookie('text['.$id.']',$cookie_value,time()+36000);
}

}
```

Comment: Não explica qual o problema que estar a ter

Comment: olha ai o problema, eu to querendo fazer isso que expliquei porem ele fica demostrando erro, esse erro daqui

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: De futuro coloque os erros que está obter para facilitar o trabalho de quem o está ajudar, coloque o erro na sua pergunta editando a mesma,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do PHP
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php

```
foreach (array_expression as $value)
    statement
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

**Erro**

$contar não é um *array*